# Grade information missing while upgrading Scorm packages from captivate to storyline

Tags: moodle, scorm, adobe-captivate, articulate-storyline

Recently we started migrating a series of SCORM packages from Adobe Captivate to Articulate Storyline. However, when uploading the end package into the LMS (Moodle), all the information regarding the grades is lost.

Besides verifying the name in the manifest, is there another way to prevent this from happening?

Open to any suggestions.

Comment: Are you replacing the old scorm packages(captivate) to new scorm package(storyline) on Moodle LMS? or making new scorm activities?
Regards

Comment: yes @Shahjahan i was able to fix the issue by controlling the name of the manifest. Manually of course.

Comment: Good to hear, so for others who want to update packages with out losing old scrom and score data, should make sure the new manifest file and old manifest files have same name and ids.

Comment: Yes.basically...
1. rename the index files

2. fix the html call on index

3. fixing the manifest